# How do I tell my handyman and his crew that they did a bad job?

Tags: conversations

**My** handyman and his crew came in, to fix a leak, and to replace our toilet. 
At the start, they did a fantastic job. But then, our kitchen was closed for a month. After they left, our toilet exploded. They came in to fix it, but then it started to leak when they left.

How do I tell them that they did a bad job, without offending anyone?

Comment: They fixed the leak, @Paparazzi. And I want to keep them because they are good at little things, but I also want them to know that they did a bad job.

Comment: I was just starting an answer to this and see that they fixed the leak.  So can I assume that this is answered?  if so, I'd suggest answering your own question so others can see how you handled this and what you learned.

Comment: Just to clarify: did they fix the leak after it started leaking after the toilet exploded?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've done a fair bit of "handyman" work, drywall, plumbing, painting, new construction, remodeling, and so on.

The last thing you want to tell a blue collar person is that they're bad at their job. People take pride in their work, even when that work includes fixing toilets. Sometimes particularly when their work includes fixing toilets... The dirtier and more unpleasant the job, the more likely people are going to be insulted that you're telling then they didn't do it right.

Try to keep in mind that sometimes things happen on a job and no one is really at fault, or at least the poor guy who did the work isn't really at fault. Parts fail, foundations shift and break pipes, and sometimes the thing that they fixed isn't even what's broken now, it's the thing they attached the new thing to.

Your profile makes it look like you write code, I'm sure you've had times where you've had to fix or patch someone else's horrifying spaghetti code. Trade work that isn't brand new construction is very often like that. You open a wall or a pipe and have to deal with whatever crazy nonsense the last person did and try to make it functional. Sometimes the last person knew what they were doing, but very often with older buildings they didn't know what they were doing or you're working with a patch on a patch on a patch.

With that in mind you probably wouldn't want to hear "you're a bad programmer" or even "you did a bad job" you'd want to hear "hey, it's throwing this error can you fix it?"

Try to understand that trade work isn't pleasant and it often doesn't pay well. At least when you're writing code people think you're smart... And honestly debugging a building is sometimes much more difficult and there's almost never any documentation.

---

With all that out of the way...

There will be times where someone honestly did just screw up. Sometimes you may have picked the cheapest contractor and they're the cheapest for a reason. It's worth noting that, like anything else, you get what you pay for...

In these cases it can be appropriate to call them up and say:

> Hey, I payed you to fix this and it's not fixed.

But tread carefully there. Did you really pay a professional for professional work, or did you pay an amateur for amateur work? If it's the latter that's kinda on you. If it's the former they'll usually go out of their way to make it right.

Comment: Totally agree. If a professional is personally offended by reclamations then you worded it badly or they are not taking it professionally. This approach is very well suited to avoid both. I'd like to add that if you (=OP) are a frequent client, they also may be interested in keeping you as such. A frequent *and content* client is worth more than just the money they are paying for the job. They probably don't want the news of "this job went horribly wrong with these guys" to spread ...

Comment: I like this answer because it addresses a way to inform the handyman that the job wasn't satisfactory without directly insulting his work.  He will likely already be ashamed/embarrassed about this under-performance in quality.

Answer (score 4):

**Don't**.

I had this experience with a contractor my parents hired to fix some plumbing in our kitchen. After they left we had a water pipe breakage there that flooded the entire kitchen. It was a total pain to clean up.

Presumably the reason why you've hired this handyman is that you can't fix these issues yourself. So don't just assume that what happened was necessarily because of them doing a bad job and not some other factor.

Hearkening back to the example I gave above, in our case, it wasn't the fault of our handyman at all - a pipe completely unrelated to what they had been working on had burst from material exhaustion. Poor timing, essentially.

While that might not be the case for you, and they might actually be at fault, you don't know that for sure. And even if you do, accusing them of doing a bad job helps nobody.

Ideally, you'd talk to them about further issues you're having. If they're honest people (I'm going to assume they are since you "do a lot of work with them" and haven't dropped them yet) they'll tell you if something was their fault after inspecting it and reaching that conclusion.

If you feel less than trusting, get another handyman to give you a second opinion and then contact your original handyman if it turns out they were at fault. Again, you want restitution, and not to just make your displeasure known. Avoid accusatory language and let them come to the conclusion that they have done a bad job themselves.

Accusing people of incompetence does not lend itself to a continued friendly relationship with them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no polite way and you'll open up a can of worms if you try.

Unless you **KNOW** that they did a bad job, they didn't.

Car mechanics and programmer go through this all the time.  Plumbers and electricians go through it even more.

Sometimes, fixing problem "X" will not cause, but REVEAL problem "Y".  Say you're dealing with a few leaks in the coolant for a car.  You fix them, and then something else starts to leak.  Why?  Did you break anything?  No.  when you fixed the leaks, you also fixed a pressure issue, which caused another hose, which was already weak, to leak because it couldn't stand up to the full pressure of the system.

So, unless you have enough skill to say

> This is happening now because X caused Y and you should have caught it because of z

You say **NOTHING**

Tradesmen take pride in their work, and calling it bad is an insult.

If it really **IS** bad, then you need to hire someone else.  There is no other alternative.